# Have bash echo the final form of executed command, can I?

Tags: bash, echo

I have a small bash script `build1c.sh` .

```
if [ "$1" = "" ]; then
    echo "You must give a .c file to compile."
    exit 1
fi

cfile=$1
stem=${cfile%.*}

set -o verbose

gcc -c -g -Wall $cfile
gcc -o $stem $stem.o common.o reentrant.o -lssl -lcrypto

set +o verbose # optional here
```

The intention is to only echo the gcc commands being executed. I work to some extend. When I call `build1c.sh client2.c` , I see output

```
gcc -c -g -Wall $cfile
gcc -o $stem $stem.o common.o reentrant.o -lssl -lcrypto

set +o verbose # optional here
```

Still wacky, right? Those var reference(`$cfile`, `$stem`) do not get their final form, so the echoing becomes pretty useless.

You know, what I like to see is

```
gcc -c -g -Wall client2.c
gcc -o client2 client2.o common.o reentrant.o -lssl -lcrypto
```

Is there correct and concise way to address this?

BTW: Minor request: Can I suppress the echoing of `set +o verbose` itself?

Comment: Have you considered using a Makefile? That's what people usually use for this.

Comment: I use makefiles a lot, but this script deals with a very trivial task so I think a Bash script is more convenient.

Comment: A Makefile would be shorter, and would do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `set -o verbose` with `set -x`

Comment: ``set -x`` does the right job, $stem is replaced with client2. But, the echo commands are prefixed with ``++``. Still waiting for possible better solution. Bash 4.1.10(4).

Answer (score 2):

```
function echo_and_execute {
    echo "$@"
    "$@"
}

echo_and_execute gcc -c -g -Wall $cfile
echo_and_execute gcc -o $stem $stem.o common.o reentrant.o -lssl -lcrypto
```

Comment: ... except that, if ``stem`` has space in it and I wrap it with double-quotes, **echo** will swallow those quotes so that the echo-ed line does not look like what is written in bash script. I know that is because passing args with $@ wipes out the pristine appearance of bash command lines.